# Recursion in a list to find all pairs in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm trying to write a function that take input a list of pairs and an element, that function will return all pairs that contains the element

this is my code:

```
(define find-node
  (lambda (x a-list)
    (if (null? a-list)
        "list null"
        (if (memq x (car a-list))
            (list (car a-list))
            (find-node x (cdr a-list))))))
```

And this is my input, for instance: '((d b a) (e c b) (e c) (d) (b e) (g f) (g))

expected output: when run `(find-node 'b '((d b a) (e c b) (e c) (d) (b e) (g f) (g)))`, output is (d b a) (e c b) (b e)

actual output from the code above: (d b a), which means that this code only run 1 time ....

Please show me where i'm wrong, i haven't been familiar with recursion much....

Comment: Looks like it's executing `(list (car a-list))` and never executing `(find-node x (cdr a-list))))))`, which means that `memq x (car a-list)` is evaluating to true.

Comment: It is, it executes recursively until it finds out the first occurrence of that element inside the nested lists, then display the pair and terminate ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not building the output list and advancing the recursion when an element is found. Try this:

```
(define find-node
  (lambda (x a-list)
    (if (null? a-list)
        '()                         ; when input is consumed, return empty list
        (if (member x (car a-list)) ; better use member
            (cons (car a-list)      ; here was the problem
                  (find-node x (cdr a-list))) ; advance the recursion
            (find-node x (cdr a-list))))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(find-node 'b '((d b a) (e c b) (e c) (d) (b e) (g f) (g)))
=> '((d b a) (e c b) (b e))
```